# How to do a reverse look up of m2m field within django template

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, many-to-many

Hello i've been trying to do a reverse m2m query and count but have failed to do so. The methods suggested by other posts dont seem to work , here is my code currently.

This is the relevant bit in my HTML:

```
    <table id='myTable' class="display ui celled table" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Company</th>
                <th>Company Address</th>
                <th>Telephone</th>
                <th>Total Projects</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

            {% for customer in customers %}
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ customer.customer_id }}</td>
                    <td><a href="{% url 'customer-profile' customer.customer_id %}" class='btn w3-teal'>{{ customer.customer_name }}</a></td>
                    <td>{{ customer.address }}</td>
                    <td>{{ customer.telephone_number}}</td>
                    {% for project in customer.salesProject_set.all %}
                    <td>{{project.count}}</td>
                    {%endfor%}
                </tr>
            {% endfor %}
    </table>
</div>
```

This is my view:

```
class CustomerView(ListView):


 model = CustomerInformation
  template_name = 'rnd/customers_all.html'
  context_object_name = 'customers'
  def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(CustomerView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['customers'] = CustomerInformation.objects.all()
    return context
```

This is my models:

```
class SalesProject(models.Model):
    customer_information = models.ManyToManyField('CustomerInformation')


class CustomerInformation(models.Model):
    customer_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    customer_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='Lee Ji Eun')
    telephone_number = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

I intend to access the m2m field within the template in order to display the relevant count of the number of projects associated with that company but the results displays nothing without throwing any error. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to do:

```
<td>{{customer.salesproject_set.all.count}}</td>
```

Instead of:

```
{% for project in customer.salesProject_set.all %}
    <td>{{project.count}}</td>
{%endfor%}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question?

Comment: thank you, yes it answers my question , sorry for the late reply , you are definitely a life saver!

Answer (score 0):

```
            {% for customer in customers %}
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ customer.customer_id }}</td>
                    <td><a href="{% url 'customer-profile' customer.customer_id %}" class='btn w3-teal'>{{ customer.customer_name }}</a></td>
                    <td>{{ customer.address }}</td>
                    <td>{{ customer.telephone_number}}</td>
                    {% for project in customer.salesproject.customer_information.all %}
                    <td>{{project.count}}</td>
                    {%endfor%}
                </tr>
            {% endfor %}
```

You can directly call this way